# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick. Application crashes

Tags: java, android

I want to create a simple quiz app, with 4 answers. It actually works, but after some time app crashes . Crash happens in different times: sometimes when i answer more than 10 questions, sometimes until 10th question, sometimes in the first question. I have spent a lot of time lookin answer on google, youtube, stackoverflow. But could not find my case

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SavolJavob"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/black">
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Payg'ambarimiz Muhammad(s.a.v) qaysi shaharda tavallud topganlar?"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/option1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Makkada"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:onClick="nextQuestion"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Madinada"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option3"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="Rimda"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/option4"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="To'gri javob yo'q"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

*SavolJavob class*

```
    package com.example.islomniorganamiz;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
public class SavolJavob extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random random=new Random();
    int questionNumber=0;
    TextView questionTextView;
    Button option1,option2,option3,option4;
    Questions questions=new Questions();
    int random_number;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_savol_javob);

        questionTextView=findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
        option1=findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option2=findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option3=findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option4=findViewById(R.id.option4);
        nextQuestion();
    }

    public void nextQuestion(){
        random_number=random.nextInt(11);
     questionTextView.setText(questions.questionsArray[random_number]);
     option1.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][0]);
     option2.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][1]);
     option3.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][2]);
     option4.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][3]);
     questionNumber++;
    }

    public void nextQuestion(View view) {
        random_number=random.nextInt(11);
        questionTextView.setText(questions.questionsArray[random_number]);
        option1.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][0]);
        option2.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][1]);
        option3.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][2]);
        option4.setText(questions.optionsArray[random_number][3]);
        questionNumber++;
    }
}
```

Questions class:

```
    package com.example.islomniorganamiz;

public class Questions {
    public String [] questionsArray={
      "1chi savol",
      "Payg'ambarimiz Muhammad(s.a.v) qaysi shaharda tavallud topganlar",
      "3chi savol",
      "4chi savol",
      "5chi savol",
      "6chi savol",
      "7chi savol",
      "8chi savol",
      "9chi savol",
      "10chi savol"
    };
    public String[][] optionsArray={
            {"1.1","1.2","1.3","1.4"},
            {"2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4"},
            {"3.1","3.2","3.3","3.4"},
            {"4.1","4.2","4.3","4.4"},
            {"5.1","5.2","5.3","5.4"},
            {"6.1","6.2","6.3","6.4"},
            {"7.1","7.2","7.3","7.4"},
            {"8.1","8.2","8.3","8.4"},
            {"9.1","9.2","9.3","9.4"},
            {"10.1","10.2","10.3","10.4"}


    };
}
```

Error:

```
03/22 21:52:27: Launching 'app' on Physical Device.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.islomniorganamiz/com.example.islomniorganamiz.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 15140 on device 'samsung-sm_a510f-3300997dc3f13377'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.islomniorganamiz-2/lib/arm
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2463)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:938)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void com.example.islomniorganamiz.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:26)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.islomniorganamiz-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.islomniorganamiz-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2463)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:938)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at void com.example.islomniorganamiz.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:26)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/Choreographer: init sf_choreo_doframe   debug_Level : 0x4f4cdebug_game_running : false
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=57
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@fda19e9[MainActivity] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -547665920} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -547665920} hwInitialized=true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -547665920}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4936f88 nm : com.example.islomniorganamiz ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=69
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@14dcfd2 nm : com.example.islomniorganamiz ic=null
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -547665920} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=67
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: setView = DecorView@355668d[Menu] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -323749888} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -323749888} hwInitialized=true
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -323749888}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ea9d042 nm : com.example.islomniorganamiz ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=73
    Input channel destroyed: fd=69
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@aadc270[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#4
    dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=57
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=false
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=69
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: setView = DecorView@1edd957[SavolJavob] touchMode=true
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true -323119104} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true -323119104} hwInitialized=true
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) or=1
    MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -323119104}
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ac83c44 nm : com.example.islomniorganamiz ic=null
I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=78
    Input channel destroyed: fd=73
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xecb48700 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xe383e450
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: mHardwareRenderer.destroy()#1
D/ViewRootImpl@4318b24[Menu]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={isValid=false 0} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@7b042d6[SavolJavob]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.islomniorganamiz, PID: 15140
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11163)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11163) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
        at com.example.islomniorganamiz.SavolJavob.nextQuestion(SavolJavob.java:44)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11163) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Try to add `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'` in build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

The indices in a 10-element array run from 0 to 9. You're trying to access element at index 10 that does not exist.

Simple fix is to change the random indexing with `nextInt(11)` to `nextInt(10)`. For better future proofing, you can also make it `nextInt(questionsArray.length)`.